# Set-Acl / takeown permission

Tags: powershell, acl, rights

I try to get myself rights on a NAS server:

```
takeown /s "KVDMTEST1" /f $path
```

Now I am owner of this path.

```
$aclLE = Get-Acl $path

$arLE = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FilesystemAccessRule("SYSTEM", "FullControl", 0, 0, "Allow")
$aclLE.SetAccessRule($arLE)

Set-Acl -Path $path -AclObject $aclLE
```

```
Set-Acl : Es wurde versucht, einen nicht autorisierten Vorgang auszuführen.
In C:\Users\bongersj\Desktop\Root_Orga anlegen.ps1:162 Zeichen:1
+ Set-Acl -Path $path -AclObject $aclLE
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : PermissionDenied: (\\KVDMTEST1\c$\fs1_KVDMTEST1\WWW:String) [Set-Acl], UnauthorizedAccessException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.UnauthorizedAccessException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SetAclCommand
```

I am still owner of the path at the end, but I have no rights to change anything. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you tried to run your script as administrator?

Comment: Do you also get an error if you try to change the permissions via `icacls`?